# maven plugin - jaxb - Creating JAXB Classes

Tags: maven, maven-3, jaxb2, jaxb2-maven-plugin

I am using JAXB plugin and need to generate classes for at least a dozens schema. 
How would i dynamically create packages corresponding to each schema ?

```
schema 1 -> package x.y.z.schema1
schema 2 -> package x.y.z.schema2.....
```

The style mentioned in JAXB2 Maven plugin makes your pom.xml very messy.

Suggested by JAXb2 Help Page :

```
<execution>
                <id>xjc-schema1</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>xjc</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <schemaFiles>schema1.xsd</schemaFiles>
                    <packageName>com.example.foo</packageName>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>xjc-schema2</id>
```

Alternatively I think a workaround would be to store this configs in a separate xml file but I dont know how to do include this in maven

Answer (score 2):

Did you try using binding file?
I used to do that with a binding file like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jaxb:bindings xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
    xmlns:inheritance="http://jaxb2-commons.dev.java.net/basic/inheritance"
    jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="inheritance" jaxb:version="2.1">

    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="../xsd/mySchema1.xsd"
        node="/xsd:schema">
         <jaxb:schemaBindings>
            <jaxb:package name="my.package.schema1" />
         </jaxb:schemaBindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>

    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="../xsd/mySchema2.xsd"
        node="/xsd:schema">
         <jaxb:schemaBindings>
            <jaxb:package name="my.package.schema2" />
         </jaxb:schemaBindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

So that in your pom you specify only the folder of all XSD and the path to the Binding file